# How to choose rows with time-stamps in a complicated range?

Tags: pandas

My data frame has a time stamp column (`dtype: datetime64[ns]`) like this

```
ID    TIMESTAMP
1     2014-08-14 17:57:17
2     2014-08-14 17:50:11
3     2014-08-14 17:49:28
4     2014-08-14 17:58:10
5     2014-08-14 17:59:37
6     2014-08-14 17:25:46
7     2014-08-14 17:54:06
8     2014-08-14 17:55:48
9     2014-08-14 17:49:23
10    2014-08-14 17:40:21
...
301   2014-12-21 14:11:52
302   2014-12-21 14:22:22
303   2014-12-21 14:29:19
304   2014-12-21 14:27:37
305   2014-12-21 14:22:33
306   2014-12-21 14:26:25
307   2014-12-21 14:11:13
308   2014-12-21 11:41:54
309   2014-12-21 13:18:44
310   2014-12-21 14:26:31
```

Now suppose I want to find the rows from 2014-08-04 to 2014-08-24, and from 17:55 to 18:00 of each day in the period, how can I do this with pandas? I think I should use `Timedelta`, but I don't find the functionality of `Timedelta` for hours only. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugly but should work for you:

```
In [113]:

df[(df['TIMESTAMP'] > '2014-08-04') & (df['TIMESTAMP'] < '2014-08-24') & (df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time > dt.time(17,55)) & (df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time < dt.time(18))]
Out[113]:
   ID           TIMESTAMP
0   1 2014-08-14 17:57:17
3   4 2014-08-14 17:58:10
4   5 2014-08-14 17:59:37
7   8 2014-08-14 17:55:48
```

So we can use date strings for comparing the date but for the time portion you'll have to construct a time object